# "g" in "Food and Cooking" banner is partially obstructed

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

See this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

from chrome 7.0.517.41 on linux.

Comment: Note: the banner logo for meta seems to just have changed for me. Maybe it was a caching/refresh issue on my end only? Feel free to close the question if it's temporary or due to local weirdness.

Comment: I saw this a while ago, but with a refresh, it went away.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Chrome likes to hang on to cached images even when you tell it to do a hard refresh...

Hit <kbd>**Shift**</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and see if that doesn't take care of it.